# What is the difference between trunc() and as.integer()?

Tags: r, performance, integer, truncate

What is the difference between `trunc()` and `as.integer()`?

Why is `as.integer` faster? Can anyone explain a bit what goes on behind the curtain?

Why does `trunc()` return class `double` instead of `integer`?

```
x <- c(-3.2, -1.8, 2.3, 1.5, 1.500000001, -1.499999999)

trunc(x)
[1] -3 -1  2  1  1 -1

as.integer(x)
[1] -3 -1  2  1  1 -1

all.equal(trunc(x), as.integer(x))
[1] TRUE

sapply(list(trunc(x), as.integer(x)), typeof)
[1] "double" "integer"

library(microbenchmark)
x <- sample(seq(-5, 5, by = 0.001), size = 1e4, replace = TRUE)
microbenchmark(floor(x), trunc(x), as.integer(x), times = 1e4)
# I included floor() as well just to see the performance difference

Unit: microseconds
          expr    min     lq      mean median     uq       max neval
      floor(x) 96.185 97.651 126.02124 98.237 99.411 67892.004 10000
      trunc(x) 56.596 57.476  71.33856 57.770 58.649  2704.607 10000
 as.integer(x) 16.422 16.715  23.26488 17.009 18.475  2828.064 10000
```

`help(trunc)`:

> "trunc takes a single numeric argument x and returns a numeric vector containing the integers formed by truncating the values in x toward 0."

`help(as.integer)`:

> "Non-integral numeric values are truncated towards zero (i.e., as.integer(x) equals trunc(x) there), [...]"

**Background**: I'm writing functions to translate between different time/date representation, such as `120403 (hhmmss) -> 43443` (seconds since 00:00:00) Performance is all that matters.

Note: this question has nothing to do with floating point arithmetic

```
SessionInfo: R version 3.3.2, Windows 7 x64
```

Comment: If you're using r for an application where the performance difference of integer truncation methods matters, reconsider using r for that application

Comment: good point. I see that for R base the question makes less sense. I forgot to mention that I'm using data.table. But still you're right, trunc() won't be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 6):

On the technical side, these functions have different goals.

The `trunc` function removes the fractional part of numbers.

The `as.integer` function converts the input values into 32-bit integers.

Thus `as.integer` would overflow on large numbers (over 2^31):

```
x = 9876543210.5

sprintf("%15f", x)
# [1] "9876543210.500000"

sprintf("%15f", trunc(x))
# [1] "9876543210.000000"

as.integer(x)
# [1] NA
```

Comment: I see, thanks. Integer overflow might be one reason R sticks to doubles. {bit64} could be a workaround. I'd like to have integers as they become row-ids to key by in data.table. In R base we usually don't care about interger/numeric (see e.g. R-Inferno by Burns), we can even subset rows by fractional numbers. However using data.table I started to differentiate.

Answer (score -1):

Values in your `vector` is already `numeric`.

`as.integer` is used to convert data to `numeric`:

```
as.integer("3.55")
# [1] 3
trunc("3.55")
# Error in trunc("3.55") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Comment: The issue here is you have quote marks around the argument. R interprets `"3.55"` as a character vector of length 1 (i.e. a string of text). The `as.integer` function is happy to coerce a character object to type integer (that's one of the things it's designed for) but `trunc` needs an argument that is numeric. `trunc(3.55)` returns `3` (with type `"double"`).